# Ensuring ScalaTest does not run in parallel

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

How can I ensure scalatest tests do not run in parallel?
Prior to 0.12 I had an sbt setting:

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
```

Newer versions introduced some complex mechanism.  Will this simpler, old way still work with 0.13?

I don't want anything to run in parallel during tests.

Answer (score 1):

That's an sbt question, and though I'm not sure what complex mechanism you are referring to, I know of no change to sbt that would cause that line to not work. Do you think you are seeing parallel execution in 0.13 with that line of code in your build?

Comment: For me it doesn't. They are still run in parallel.